# MSIEXEC what is the difference between qn and quiet

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I want to make a silent installation of an MSI file.

What is the difference between **/qn** and **/quiet** as parameters to **msiexec.exe**?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no difference.  /q(x) existed since the initial versions of MSI and /quiet was added later in MSI 3.0 (Presumably to make it easier to understand by users.)

[Command-Line Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (All Versions)

[Standard Installer Command-Line Options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (MSI 3.0+)

> /quiet
>
> Note  The equivalent Windows Installer Command-Line Option is /qn.